# Run command after nice command has finished

Tags: backup, scp, scheduling, nice

I have 3 `nice` commands that are dumping some databases, and compress assets for a backup. After that, the files should be copied to another server. I'm using this command:

```
nice mysqldump -u user1 -p'XXX' database1 | gzip > database1.sql.gz
nice mysqldump -u user2 -p'XXX' database2 | gzip > database2.sql.gz
nice zip -r assets.zip /var/www/site1/assets/

cd ..

scp -R backups user@backupserver.com:/home/user/backups
```

My problem is, that the `scp` commands seems to get executed, BEFORE the nice commands are finished. This leads to partial SQL dumps, and sometimes broken zip files.

So how can I be sure, that all 3 nice commands are finished, before copying the files to another server?

Comment: Is this all inside of a bash script (`somescript.bash`), and none of these are backgrounded, correct? If so I don't see how the next command could start until the prior one was done.

Comment: There is probably another reason your `mysqldump` is incomplete (eg a corrupt table).

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `wait` shell built in.

Execute commands in the background, then tell the shell to wait for all of them to finish before continuing. Here's a very basic example:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 6 && echo first sleep  &
WAITPID="$!"
sleep 3 && echo second sleep &
WAITPID="$WAITPID $!"

echo "waiting"
wait $WAITPID
echo "done waiting"
```

Notes:

- The `pid` of background processes is collected into `WAITPID` and the list is fed to `wait`. You can also use job numbers instead.
- When you run this you'll see that `second sleep` finishes first.